# Kendo UI Mvc Grid Title template

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Using read action I am getting grid data as json and gets binded in the grid with the title marked as bold:

**Name | PRICE**

XXX  |   5
YYY  |   10
ZZZ  |   15

After binding all values, Now I have to display the grid with the title like below:

**Name | PRICE(30)**

XXX  |   5
YYY  |   10
ZZZ  |   15

Is there a ClientTemplate for "Title" to do this? Instead of javascript looping and changing the title text? If so please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kendo UI Grid does have [headerTemplate](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.headerTemplate) where you can make calculation and change appearance of column header.

```
// Example kendoGrid use of column.headerTemplate
var templateFunction = function(shouldBeColumn) {
    // shouldBeColumn is an empty object rather than the column object
    return "Useless object:" + kendo.stringify(shouldBeColumn);
};

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: products,
        pageSize: 20
    },
    height: 550,
    scrollable: true,
    columns: [
        { field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
        { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", headerTemplate: plainTemplate },
        { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", headerTemplate: templateFunction }
    ]
});
```